# parse error when handling strings

Tags: c, string, yacc, lex

```
%option case-insensitive
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno


id              [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*

integer         (0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)|([0-9]+)

real            [0-9]*\.[0-9](e|E)?[0-9]*

undefined       [^"\r\n \t]

%x STR
%%
\" string_buf_ptr = string_buf; BEGIN(STR);

<STR>\"        { /* saw closing quote - all done */
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
    *string_buf_ptr = '\0';
    /* return string constant token type and
     * value to parser
     */

     yylval.strVal = strdup(string_buf);
     sprintf(yyout, yylval.strVal);
     return STR;
    }

<STR>\\n  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\n';
<STR>\\t  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\t';
<STR>\\r  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\r';
<STR>\\b  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\b';
<STR>\\f  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\f';

<STR>\\(.|\n)  *string_buf_ptr++ = yytext[1];

<STR>[^\\\n\"]+        {
    char *yptr = yytext;

    while ( *yptr )
            *string_buf_ptr++ = *yptr++;
    }
```

This is part of my code for the lexical analysis of strings. The goal of this code is to locate strings (C-like strings ex. `"Hello World"`) and return them to our parser for handling.

I've also constructed a parser using the `Yacc` tool and it's almost perfect except from when we are assigning strings to variables (ex. `x="Hello World";`)
When I do that, the `yyerror(const char*)` function is invoked and the message is `unexpected $undefined.` I cannot understand why this is happening. The reduction should recognize a `left value` `x`, an `assignment` and a `constant String` `"Hello World"`, what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've apparently defined `STR` as both a token and a lex start state.  Both of these are actually macros (that expand to integer constant literals), so you probably have a warning about the macro `STR` being redefined somewhere in you compiler output.  The `return STR;` in your code above ends up returning the start-state code for `STR` instead of the token code, which the bison-generated parser does not recognize as a valid token code.